# Finding Query that Triggered a Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, delete-row, database-trigger

Is it possible with a trigger to get the query or primary id of the query that triggered it?

Currently we roughly have:

```
Delete from Table1 where id = 1
```

(`id` is the primary id of that table, `1` is just an example record)

I want to log the query or the `id` of the row being deleted (because someone is incorrectly deleting records (not malicious)). This seemed like it'd be an easy process with a `trigger` and `BEFORE DELETE ON` but I can't figure out how to address the parent query that caused the `trigger` to fire.

I planned to have:

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER Table1_Row_Being_Deleted
        BEFORE DELETE ON Table1
            INSERT INTO deleted_Table1 (deleting_date, tableid) values(now(), ?);
    END$$
DELIMITER;
```

But I don't know what to put for the `?`. All other threads and docs I've seen have had static values, or affected every row in the table.

Comment: The id that is going to be deleted is `old.id`. The tablename is 'Table1' (a trigger always belongs to a specific table, so you know that tablename when you create the trigger). You should use `FOR EACH ROW`, otherwise you don't log multiple deletes. And you can't know which statement tries to delete the row. And you will log even if the delete will fail afterwards (e.g. because of a foreign key), you can use `after delete` to log only successful deletes.

Comment: `you can't know which statement tries to delete the row` That is exactly what I need to know though. There is no system level event that this can be traced from? If I use `after delete` isn't the record already gone or is it temporarily stored in the memory and still accessible? There will never be 2 deleted records in one query so I don't need to worry about multiple deletes in one query.

Comment: `old` is a special row that contains the value even after deletion. To trace your query, you might want to check out `performance_schema.events_statements` and/or `performance_schema.events_statements_history` (you have to set an option for the last one), they containt active and past querys. They are not directly linked to your trigger event, but maybe you can link somehow (e.g. by a timestamp, or by checking if the table name is in the string, although it is of course possible to delete a row indirectly, so the tablename might not be in the querytext, or save several queries and check later)

Comment: Yup, `old` is the answer. Thanks, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I posted it as an answer and added the stuff about the event-log, might help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct link between the trigger and the query that triggered the trigger. But you can use the `performance schema` to search for all active queries and log them. One of them should be the caller's query.

```
create trigger Table1_Row_Being_Deleted after delete on Table1 
for each row
  insert into deleted_Table1(id, dt, user, qry) 
  select old.id, now(), user(), performance_schema.events_statements_current.sql_text
  from performance_schema.events_statements_current;
```

This will log every active query, and thus a lot of noise, because the correct query is not known. Since it can be an indirect query (e.g. from a procedure), the correct query will not always have a distinctive part like 'delete from table1' in it. So look for common queries that will be in the logtable every time your problem occurs.

I used an `after delete` trigger here, so it will only log when `delete` succeeded, you might want to use a `before delete` trigger to log even if the `delete` will fail later (e.g. because of foreign key constraint).

`old.id` (and the whole row `old`) contains the values the row had before it was deleted (so you can still use it here to log the entry).

The `performance schema` and the `events_statements_current`-log are usually enabled by default. Check the result from

```
select * from performance_schema.events_statements_current;
```

It should at least contain a row with this `select`-query itself (since that was an active query at that time). If it is empty (or you have no permission to use that or it doesn't exists), you should check if `show variables like 'performance_schema';` will show `ON`. And you might need to set permissions or some logging options, see [Query Profiling Using Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html).